# How do I rewrite this code to accept user input?

Tags: c#

I have the following code which prints the area of a [right triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_triangle). As you can see the dimensions of the triangles are hard coded into the program. I wish for the user to input the values `x` and `y`. How would I go about changing the below program so that the user is prompted to enter these values?

```
public class Triangle
{        
    private int height, length;        
    public Triangle(int x, int y)
    {
        length = x;
        height = y;
    }       
    public double TriArea()
    {
        double area;
        area = 0.5 *(height * length);
        return area;
    }
}
class TriangleArea
{
    public static void Main()
    {            
        Triangle Tri1 = new Triangle(15, 10);            
        Console.WriteLine("Area 1=" + Tri1.TriArea());           
        Triangle myTriangle = new Triangle(12, 5);            
        Console.WriteLine("My Triangle Area =" + myTriangle.TriArea());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is the issue you're trying to resolve? You haven't provided any useful information. Please add more details, particularly what you mean by "user input".

Comment: I realy dont know how to put this in english, my grammar is bad. But i will try my best to put this. What i mean is the ones without value where the value of the height and length is put by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A naïve approach would be to do the following.

```
Console.WriteLine("Add integer X: ");
int x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("Add integer Y: ");
int y = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Triangle Tri1 = new Triangle(x, y);            
Console.WriteLine("Area 1=" + Tri1.TriArea());
```

A more robust approach would be to validate user input and have an input loop so that the user can calculate the area of more than one triangle. It could look like the following:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool keepPrompting = true;

    while (keepPrompting)
    {
        bool weHaveValidXValue = false;
        int x = 0, y = 0;

        while (!weHaveValidXValue)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter value for X and press return:");

            string xValue = Console.ReadLine();

            weHaveValidXValue = int.TryParse(xValue, out x);

            if (!weHaveValidXValue || x <= 0)
            {
                weHaveValidXValue = false;
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid value");
            }
        }

        bool weHaveValidYValue = false;

        while (!weHaveValidYValue)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter value for Y and press return:");

            string yValue = Console.ReadLine();

            weHaveValidYValue = int.TryParse(yValue, out y);

            if(!weHaveValidYValue || y <= 0)
            {
                weHaveValidYValue = false;
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid value");
            }
        }

        Triangle myTriangle = new Triangle(x, y);

        Console.WriteLine("My Triangle Area = {0}", myTriangle.TriArea());

        Console.WriteLine("Continue? (y/n)");

        string response = Console.ReadLine();

        if(response.Equals("n", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            keepPrompting = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And now if I type: ABCDEFG it crashes everything. DO NOT TRUST USER INPUT

Comment: @Steve And Now I WROTE to make validation if he wants ... Write the whole post next time

Comment: Then why suggesting an answer that is doomed to fail? Put directly the correct validation code and your answer will be fine today for him and tomorrow for future readers. (By the way the downvote is not mine but...)

Comment: I think its working, thanks thou. But incase i got this the wrong way, ill get back to here. lol

Comment: @Steve I have added a more robust example.

Comment: @BryanOyster take a look at the new example.

Comment: @KlausByskovPedersen that's a big improvement

Comment: @KlausByskovPedersen wow, this is far from i expected.